# why are the bars on the left instead of the right and why does the small screen version need to slide instead of using the function to see the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, menu

Hi guys I'm trying to create a mobile friendly header menu with the bars on the right side of the screen. A Javascript for clicking the cross and the bars for opening the menu on the right. Except I have a

1. the bars are on the left and should be on the right

Can someone help me and give me some insights?

[image: this is how it look in small screen]

here's the html code I have

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <section class="header">
        <nav>
            
            <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="endangered.html">Endangered</a> </li>
                                
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu"></i>
        </nav>

    </section>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

here is the css code

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
    
}

.header{ 
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-links{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5ab61d;
    
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    background: #0ace83;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nav-links li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}

nav .fa{
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
    .nav-links ul li{
        display: block;

    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        background: #f44336;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: -200px;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    nav .fa{
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-links ul{
        padding: 30px;
    }
}
```

and here is the javascript

```
/* Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks */
    var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks")
    function showMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "0";
    }
    function hideMenu(){
        navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }
```

I have been trying to figure out what's wrong for hours help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have an error here : <i class="fa fa-bars" oneclick="showMenu"></i>.
It's onclick, or in your js with addEventListener('click', fn);

Comment: thx yeah now javascript works except do you know how i can move the three bars to the left of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the event element in your icon oneclick="showMenu" by onclick="showMenu".

For the burger position you can

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Should work because your nav panel is on absolute position, but maibe it's better isolate your icon from nav element.